# How to write monomials in $GF(2^n)$ as a system of equations in $GF(2)$

Tags: symmetric, pseudo-random-function, finite-field

Let $F = GF(2^n)$ and $P(x) = x^e, P : F \rightarrow F$ be a monomial of degree $e$. How to write each bit of the output of $P$ as a function of input bits? In other words, how to write it as a system of polynomials over $GF(2)$?
One way is to use computer algebra systems such as sage and work as follow:

```
sage: p = 2
sage: n = 4
sage: F.<a> = GF(p^n)
sage: R = PolynomialRing(F, n, names='c')
sage: c = R.gens()
sage: f = sum(c[i]*a^i for i in range(n)); f
c0 + a*c1 + (a^2)*c2 + (a^3)*c3
sage: I = R.ideal([g^p - g for g in c])
sage: P = sum(vector(b)*m.reduce(I) for b,m in f^3); P
(c0*c2 + c1*c2 + c1*c3 + c0, c0*c1 + c0*c2 + c2*c3 + c3, c0*c1 + c0*c2 + c1*c2 + c0*c3 + c1*c3 + c2*c3 + c2, c1*c3 + c2*c3 + c1 + c2 + c3)
```

But this is inefficient, especially when n is large (128 or more). What is the better way to do it?

Comment: In $GF(2^n)$, the polynomial $x^e$ is linear in $GF(2)$ when $e$ is a power of 2; that is, it has a fairly simple representation (all terms are of degree one).  One approach would be to express $e$ as a sum of powers of two (that is, in binary), express each power of two as the simple polynomial in $GF(2)$, and then multiply them together.  The last step is tricky; however for nonpowers of 2, I believe the ultimate expression will be somewhat complicated anyways...

Comment: May I ask, why you want to represent each output bit as function of input bits? What do you want to achieve using this representation? (If the Hamming weight of the exponent e is big, the functions will be quite complicated and the expression as ands/xors might be huge - the Hamming weight is the algebraic degree of your monomial, i.e. the maximal number of input bits in an and.)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can take a table of values for $P$ and convert it to algebraic normal form via the M"{o}bius transform.  For $n$ as large as you're talking about, anything you do will be unwieldy unless the algebraic degree of $x^e$ (i.e. the Hamming weight of $e$) is small.  The output bits of the ANF are polynomials in $n$ variables and there are $2^n$ possible monomials that can appear.

For example, here is a picture of the ANF for $x^{254}$ over $GF(2^8)$ (AES inversion), showing which monomials appear in each of the 8 output bits:
[image]

Comment: Nice picture, where did you get it from?

Comment: I made it following the description in my answer (python, matplotlib.pyplot.imshow, it's a heat map of the zero-one values).

Comment: Indeed, when the algebraic degree is small the representation should not be big. But using Mobius transform requires the truth table which in my case is not feasible.